# Pipe and Redirection in UEFi-Shell does not work

Tags: uefi

In order to do simple checks (e.g. date) without using files I tried the following (without sucess):

Store date in enviroment variable:

```
fs0:\> date >v date_var
Shell: Incorrect redirection syntax - '>v'
```

as an alternative I tried to pipe the result of date:

```
fs0:\> date | check_date.nsh
date: Too many arguments
```

Do I need certain lib or command level to run the above character sequences?

---

I´m using a uefi shell with:

```
EFI Shell version 2.40 [5.10]
Current running mode 1.1.2
...
fs0:\> ver
EFI Specification Revision : 2.40
```

[Uefi_Shell_Spec_2_2](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_2_2.pdf) chapter 3.4.4 let me think that both should work fine.

Comment: Whar version of the shell are you using, my v2.2 shell prints this when running the 'ver' command?

Comment: I added the information to my question. It´s 2.4 as I understand. After all as the `>v` and pipe operations are already defined in [Uefi Shell 2.0](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_Spec_2_0.pdf) I think this is not the problem.

Comment: A shell version 2.4 is not specified, this may be a custom implementation not following the specification. Are you using a built-in shell or have you built it yourself?

Comment: @MiSimon Thanks fpr your comment. I build a selfmade shell and yes, there the `>v` works fine. I was too naive to think the built-in shell will follow the spec.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, UEFI shell does not support process piping, nor variable piping, so you cannot chain outputs, but it do support file redirections.

try to use `data > date_file`.

Comment: If the shell is fully compatible to the specification (>2.0) redirecting to a variable (environment not nvram) and piping should work. Maybe this features are not required for lower support levels (there are 4 support levels for uefi shells).